# How to show/hide a MODAL based on selected multiple value in select with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal with a multiple select: If the user chooses "Four" among its options, I want the next modal to be displayed, which would be modal2, but if the user does not choose "Four" among its options, I want modal2 to be hidden and jump to modal 3.

```
<div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog" data-modalorder="1">
   <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
      <h1">Select your options</h1>
      <form id="form_intereses">
         <select id="number_selection" name="number_selection" multiple>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
            <option value="4">Four</option>
            <option value="5">Five</option>
         </select>
         <input class="getAssignment" type="submit" value="Siguiente">
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog" data-modalorder="2">
   <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
      <h1 class="estilo_mobile">Title if selected number four</h1>
      <p>If selected "number four" show this content, if not hide this div and skip to the   next</p>
      <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Siguiente">
   </div>
</div>
<div id="openModal3" class="modalDialog" data-modalorder="3">
   <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
      <h1 class="estilo_mobile">Title if not selected number four</h1>
      <p>If not selected numer four show content</p>
      <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Siguiente">
   </div>
</div>
<script>
   
      var options = document.getElementById('number_selection').selectedOptions;
      var values = Array.from(options).map(({ value }) => value);

      if(values.includes("Four")){
       document.getElementById('openModal3').style.display = "block";
      } else{
       document.getElementById('openModal3').style.display = "none";
      }
    
</script>
```

- Case 1: If for example the user chooses number one, two and five BUT he does not choose "number four" I want DIV #2 to hide and skip to DIV #3
- Case 2: If for example the user chooses number one, two and "four", I want DIV #2 to be displayed and follow the normal flow.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, but you're checking if the value is "Four", which is the text and not the value. The value is "4".

```
const options = document.getElementById('number_selection').selectedOptions;
const values = Array.from(options).map(({ value }) => value);

if(values.includes("4")){
  document.getElementById('openModal2').style.display = "block";
} else{
  document.getElementById('openModal3').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: With this I manage to hide the next modal, but it closes and I can't jump to modal3. I click on my "Next" button and the third modal is no longer rendered, everything closes